# Why do the hash functions tested by SMhasher appear to be exceptionally fast?

Tags: hash, performance

In [SMhasher](https://github.com/rurban/smhasher), it seems that data (keys) are read one by one sequentialy, and not splited and:

```
MiB/sec: The average of the Bulk key speed test for alignments 0-7 with 262144-byte keys. The higher the better.
```

/\ This is written in its README.

The author said that are the output of hash functions that is measured.

Take a fast hash function tested by SMhasher, for example Blake3, it has 1288.84 MiB/S is a modern processor.

As the output is measured, 1288.84 MiB/S equals ~1351446691-bytes that means ~42232709 outputs of Blake3, each output has 32-byte (256-bits).

But if we multiply the number of Blake3 invocations per 262144-byte keys hashed sequentially as input we have this: 42232709 * 262144 = 11071051268096-bytes read as input (11.07-terabytes).

How can it be possible that the input of a hash function tested can read data at 11.07-terabytes per second?

Comment: These are not all cryptographic hashes (Blake3 is though). Generally you perform SELECT's and searches using the DB keys. The key is the **input** of the hash function to build up a fast internal hash table. The key is hashed again to perform the lookup.

Comment: "The author said that are the output of hash functions that is measured." Can you show exactly where the author said that? This looks like a case of a misunderstood question, a badly written reply, or a misinterpretation of said reply. 1.3 GB/s of **input** data is the reasonable value here.