# Once a secure hash function built up a (fast) internal hash table, can data to be hashed be different from the data inserted when doing the lookups?

Tags: hash, seed

[One experienced user of this forum said](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/105603/why-do-the-hash-functions-tested-by-smhasher-appear-to-be-exceptionally-fast?noredirect=1#comment226085_105603): "The key is the input of the hash function to build up a fast internal hash table. The key is hashed again to perform the lookup.".

If I hash a data such as a 262144-bytes seed (as [SMhasher](https://github.com/rurban/smhasher) does) is passed through a hash function to build up a fast internal hash table, can the secondary lookups include different data such as a counter appended to the seed again? I mean if some bytes can be appended to the seed to be hashed and reuse the same internal hash table again, not having to rebuild it again.

For example:

H(S)...H(01|S)...H(02|S)...H(03|S)...H(03|S)...

H is the hash, S is the seed, 01, 02, 03 the counter, all hashed sequentially. The H(S) hashed first should build the internal hash table for subsequent lookups.

Comment: Your question could really use a concrete example of what you're trying or expecting to achieve. Missing that, I can only speak generically: if the question is whether there is a simple relationship between any two inputs (related, as you're suggesting, or not) to a secure hash function, such as SHA-3, then the answer is no.

Comment: @swineone I want to know if I could freely use a large seed with a hash function for encryption, hashing a 4096-byte seed and produce a 32-byte output would make the speed of output be terrible slow. Without the need to rebuild the internal hash table of a hash function would make the output be way faster, but as you said "no", I'm giving up that idea. Thanks!